# What is the difference between a term and a word?

Tags: meaning

I know a word is more specific compared to a term but i don't know which one is definitive or the actual meaning of the two.

Comment: If you need to know the actual meaning of a word, the dictionary is a good place to start. If you [edit] your question to explain what you found when you looked up "term" and "word" and why that didn't help you, we may be able to reopen it.

Comment: I admit it is. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word is language that is officially accepted,has an official definition, and is understood the same by everyone in general. A term is language used formally or informally that may be understood among some or a specific group (such as within an industry, a gang, a culture) but not everyone. For example slang.

Answer (score 0):

We say "term" when discussing a word that has a specific meaning in a special context. Like someone might say, "What is the term in chemistry for a substance that ..." "Word" is more general. "The" and "dog" are words. You'd rarely refer to them as "terms".

Also, a "term" can be more than one word. Like you might say, "The term for that is 'style injection'", i.e. two words making up a single term.